# How can I combine two Excel formulas into one?

Tags: windows-7, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, if

In a spreadsheet, I have five columns (total) and four of them have the components of the students' grade. The fifth has the final grade.

Now, I need to combine two formulas so that when the four columns have the grades, the first formula executes and when columns 1 and 2 have the grades, the second formula executes.

1st formula:

```
=(CEILING(IF(AND(D2=97;E2=97);(F2+G2*2+F2+G2*4)/8;IF(D2=97;(F2+E2*2+F2+G2*4)/8;IF(E2=97;(D2+G2*2+F2+G2*4)/8;(D2+E2*2+F2+G2*4)/8)));0.25))
```

2nd formula:

```
=(CEILING(IF(AND(D2=97);(E2*2)/2;IF(E2=97;(D2*1)/1;(D2+E2*2)/3));0.25))
```

Comment: The correct formulas are:                              1 =(CEILING(IF(AND(D2=97;E2=97);(F2+G2*2+F2+G2*4)/8;IF(D2=97;(F2+E2*2+F2+G2*4)/8;IF(E2=97;(D2+G2*2+F2+G2*4)/8;(D2+E2*2+F2+G2*4)/8)));0.25))                 2=(CEILING(IF(AND(D2=97);(E2*2)/2;IF(E2=97;(D2*1)/1;(D2+E2*2)/3));0.25))

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! You can edit your question if required by pressing the [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1759904/edit) button.

Comment: “Can Excel solver help me?” That was your original question title. That title says nothing but “Please help me.” and that is not a question. I [edited and reworked the question title to actually ask a question](https://superuser.com/posts/1759904/revisions). This community can help you if you show effort and actually do the minimal work required to ask a basic question.

Comment: Thank you
That's kind of you.